# In javascript, alias namespace?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, shouldn't I alias a namespace?

In the *Naming* chapter of *[Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming)*, it says:

```
//Do not alias namespaces.
myapp.main = function() {
  var namespace = some.long.namespace;
  namespace.MyClass.staticHelper(new namespace.MyClass());
};
```

But I cannot fully understand this issue. Why not alias a namespace for brevity?

Answer (score 6):

You change `this`, which could break functions in the aliased namespace. Example:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        console.log(this.baz);
    },
    baz: 42
};

foo.bar(); // prints 42
var alias = foo.bar;
alias(); // prints undefined, because `this` is no longer `foo`
```

Comment: `var alias = foo.bar.bind(foo);` :p

Comment: @jAndy yes, but that only works because my example is simple and the alias is to a function, not a "namespace"/object (as I'm sure you know). I'll update for clarity++.

Comment: Namespaces are not functions usually, though, but rather objects containing e.g. functions. But it's good to mention this.

Comment: `var alias = foo.bar; alias.call(foo);`

Comment: @MattBall: indeed. But you could also workaround that issue using a construct like `Function.prototype.call.bind( OBJ/METHOD );`. My point actually was that Googles guide is a little to tunnelvisioned there.

Comment: In the example, alias will change `this`, but `foo.bar` is not a namespace. In fact `foo` is the _namespace_, it seems that I won't change `this` if I alias `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

The document explicitly says you *should* alias long namespaced types locally:

> Use local aliases for fully-qualified types if doing so improves readability. The name of a local alias should match the last part of the type.

However, except for reference safety I can't imagine why you shouldn't alias namespaces

The problem with an aliased namespace is that the references don't point to the same instances anymore.

```
my.long.namespaces.myFunc()
// this refers to the same function, but is a different reference
var myLocalNamespace = my.long.namespace;
namespace.myFunc();
// and you can easily introduce bugs which are hard to find
myLocalNamespace.myFunc = "foobar";
myLocalNamespace.myFunc()  // throws a type error because myFunc is now a string
```

This bug is hard to search for.

Aliasing has a lot of benefits though. Each member lookup in JavaScript costs time. So having code that constantly needs to lookup a chain of members is wasted speed. Since the cost of a local `var` is negligible it is strongly advised using local vars whenever you are referring to long namespaces, function results (like `$("something")`) and so on. Also, it makes your code much more readable. Consider the following:

```
var handleNamespace = function() {
    my.really.long.namespace.foo = "bar";
    my.really.long.namespace.doIt(my.really.long.namespace.foo);
    my.really.long.namespace.member = my.really.long.namespace.somethingElse(my.really.long.namespace.addOne(2));
};
```

As you see this gets confusing rather quickly. Getting rid of repeated code saves processing power and makes your code more readable.

```
var handleNamespace = function() {
    var namespace = my.really.long.namespace,
        three = namespace.addOne(2);

    namespace.foo = "bar";
    namespace.doIt(namespace.foo);
    namespace.member = namespace.somethingElse(three);
};
```

Comment: "because you only changed the member of alias" - this is not correct. An object is shared between the places it is stored.

Comment: Of course. Sorry my mistake. I'll update the answer. I was actually thinking about the reference itself being exchangeable not the members.

Answer (score 3):

I think this rule applies to namespace objects only:

> The name of a local alias should match the *last part* of the type.

What you should alias (see the rule one above) are the things you really want to use, in here the `MyClass` constructor/namespace.

Improveded code:

```
myapp.main = function() {
  var myClass = some.long.namespace.MyClass;
  myClass.staticHelper(new myClass());
};
```

Of course, this does not apply to the namespaces whose several properties you want to use. If your code had also a need for `namespace.TheirClass`, it would be OK.